# dyndns and gmail: can I use my own domain with a gmail account?

Tags: email, gmail

Simple question (I hope) - but I seem to have struggled to find the answer to it.

can I use gmail with DynDns?

I have my own domain, and would like to have emails come from and be sent to my own domain.

Googling around, I think that this can be only done if you have the full paid-for google app suite, and not just with the free gmail - but don't seem to be able to find a definitive answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not use gmail with DynDNS (or another dns service). to do that, you need an own domain (and a google apps for business account) in which you define DNS mail exchange (MX) records which direct mail for your domain to the google apps for business mail server.

**note:** as of december 6, 2012 google does not offer free google apps accounts anymore -> reference : https://support.google.com/a/answer/2855120